# Condition for connectedness of two open ball

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

What is the condition on $p, q, r_1, r_2 $ such that $B(p,r_1) \cup B(q, r_2)$ is connected in $\mathbb{R^n}$?

We know that if the intersection is non empty then union is connected but how to find condition? Plese help.

Comment: Draw a picture in the plane.  It has to do with the distance between the two centers, and the two radii.

Answer (score 0):

The intersection point lays in $B(p,r_1)$ and $B(q,r_2)$, hence it has distance of $p$ less than $r_1$ and of $q$ less than $r_2$. Using triangle inequality, what does this mean to the distance of $p$ and $q$.

To show this is enough look at the line joining $p$ and $q$ and choose a point in appropriate distance of $p$. On this line the triangle inequality is an equality, hence if you chose the appropriate distance, it should still lay in $B(q,r_2)$ (if the distance of $p$ and $q$ is small enough). (What is small enough? :-) )

Comment: yea, got it, i think result is $\vert \vert p-q \vert \vert <r_1 +r _2$

Comment: @1256 Yes, you got it :-)